# Fetch Twitter Feeds without login and Instagram images

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to fetch Feeds of a Twitter page without login And recent Images from Instagram page.

I tried this https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=QFRadio2&count=2 , for fetching Tweets, But it returns

```
{"errors":[
            {
               "message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215
            }
          ]
}
```

Any help for fetching Twitter's feeds And Instagram images of a page without login.

```
NSDictionary    *Dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kTwitter_oauth_access_token,@"oauth_access_token",kTwitter_oauth_access_token_secret, @"oauth_access_token_secret",kTwitter_consumer_key,@"consumer_key",kTwitter_consumer_secret,@"consumer_secret", nil];
    NSString *string = [Dic JSONRepresentation];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[ NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=QFRadio2&count=2&"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: [string UTF8String] length: [string length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: data];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
```

Comment: I am using this //[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=mobtuts&rpp=5"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/QFRadio/home_timeline.json?q=QFRadio&rpp=5"]];
 [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: Twitter requires authentication, without it, you will not be able to fetch any data from the API. Please read about the changes here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview